# Cutting down JQuery repetitive code

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

In a Jquery code I've the following situation:

```
$("#input_field").on('input', function () {
    setTimeout(function (e) {
        $.post("endpoint.php", $('#main').serialize(), function (response) {
            parseRes(response);
        });
    }, 1);
});
$("#input_field").on("paste", function () {
    setTimeout(function (e) {
        $.post("endpoint.php", $('#main').serialize(), function (response) {
            parseRes(response);
        });
    }, 1);
});
```

The only different thing is the event ("input" or "paste").

Is there any way to avoid this kind of repetitions (eg. adding more events to ONE code block)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
>
> events: One or more space-separated event types and
>   optional namespaces, such as "click" or "keydown.myPlugin".

This means your code simply boils down to:

```
$("#input_field").on('input paste',function() {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try,

```
 $("#input_field").on('input paste',function() {
     setTimeout(function(e) {
       $.post("endpoint.php", $('#main').serialize(), function (response) {
          parseRes(response);
        });
       }, 1);
  });
```

Please read [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to know more about `.on()`